# Two variables that are true return false in (tmp1 == tmp2). Why?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I just came upon one problem. I wanted to compare whether my Eratostenes's Sieve contains prime numbers or not. In the code i have this line

```
if (sieve[2] == is_prime(2)) // returns false
    printf ("true");
```

Now, sieve[2] is a boolean and it's value is true (I even checked in the array, so there's no doubt about it). is_prime(2) is a boolean aswell (I also checked).

Now my problem. The line presented above returns false. Yes - it returns false even though it's statement is:

```
if ( true == true )  // which normally returns true
    printf ("true");
```

However, after removing one equation sign:

```
if ( sieve[2] = is_prime(2) ) // returns true
    printf ("true");
```

This statement returns true.

Can someone briefly explain how does one equation mark work in this case in comparison to ==?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

is_prime:

```
bool is_prime(int x) {
    unsigned int i,j,k;
    if (x < 2) return false;
    else {
        for (i=2; i!=x; i++) {
            if (x == i) return true;
            else if (x % i == 0) return false;
        }
    }
}
```

sieve:

```
const int n = 10000;
bool sieve[n+1];
.
.
unsigned long int i;
sieve[0] = sieve[1] = false;
for (i=2; i<=n; i++) sieve[i] = true;
for (i=2; i*i<=n; i++) {
    if (sieve[i]) {
        unsigned tmp = 2*i;
        while (tmp <= n) {
            sieve[tmp] = false;
            tmp += i;
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT2]
The problem was with "is_prime(x)" Changed loop condition from "i!=x" to "i<=x"
Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the answers

Comment: `=` is `operator=` which always return true

Comment: You should post some code for is_prime

Comment: this is `sieve[2] = is_prime(2)` assignment.

Comment: @Astose no, `true == true` is obviously `true` so 1) you're watching wrong thing (for example step by step debugging in release mode) or 2) there is something (!) wrong with your compiler. `=` isn't same as `==`, it'll assign _rhs_ to _lhs_ and (for primitive type or where coded like that) will return _lhs_ to evaluate to `bool`: `if (a = 1)` will assign `1` to `a` and return `a`, `1` will be evaluated as `true`).

Comment: @billz No it doesn't.

Comment: Little of what you claim here rings true. Please show an MCVE.

Comment: @Astose Are you sure `is_prime`'s result is invariant across calls? If not, just by probing its value, you might have caused the later `if` to fail.

Comment: *How* do you check the values? By printing them out? In a debugger?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg by checking whether statement is true and then printing it into console

Comment: @billz It will convert the assigned to type to `bool`, and return that.  In most cases (user defined types which don't convert implicitly to anything else), it won't compile.

Comment: @Astose please check `sieve[2]` again.

Comment: By "boolean", do you literally mean type `bool` (not some other type being interpreted as a boolean)? And are you initialising them, so they have a definite `true` or `false` value? If not, they could have non-zero values which look "trueish" but don't compare equal. In any case, please post a complete test case to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 6):

### UPDATE

```
bool is_prime(int x) {
    unsigned int i,j,k;
    if (x < 2) return false;
    else {
        for (i=2; i!=x; i++) {
            if (x == i) return true;
            else if (x % i == 0) return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `is_prime()` (above) is broken, with ***undefined behaviour***, as when `x` is `2` (or indeed any actually prime number) it reaches the end of the function without having a `return` statement - the `i!=x` test means the `x == i` inside the loop can never be `true`.

`is_prime(2)` it's likely to return effectively random results (based on left over stack or register content / in your documented output it's seeming "returning" `x` itself, presumably because your ABI uses the same CPU register or stack address to pass in the argument and pass back the function's return value).

Specifically for 2, flow enters the first `else` clause, then with `i=2` the first `i!=x` test fails and the `for` loop immediately exits... there's no `return` after the `for`'s scope.  Minimally corrected code (faster implementations are possible, but keeping the simplicity and intended logic):

```
bool is_prime(int x)
{
    if (x < 2) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i < x; ++i)
         if (x % i == 0)
             return false;
    return true;
}
```

### Equivality / `==`

With `sieve[2] == is_prime(2)` it's checking they have the same value - possibly after converting one of the values to enable the comparison, but you say they're both booleans so that's not necessary.  This would yield a "true" value for the `if` when they're both `true` or both `false`.

> Now my problem. The line presented above returns false. Yes - it returns false even though...

That doesn't make any sense... I suggest you add the following before the `if` statement to check the variables' values:

```
std::cout << "sieve[2] " << sieve[2] << " (bool)" << (bool)sieve[2]
      << ", is_prime(2) " << is_prime(2) << std::endl;
```

> I even checked in the array, so there's no doubt about it

Be wary of mistakes like seeing the array content displayed ala { true false true false } and thinking `[2]` is the second value... it's actually the third. as array indexing starts at 0.

### Assignment / `=`

With `sieve[2] = is_prime(2)` you're assigning the value of `is_prime(2)` into `sieve[2]`, and the `if` statement is deemed "true" if that value is deemed true in a boolean context (i.e. it's a boolean with value `true`, or a non-0 number or pointer etc.).  For most data types, the execution flow of `if (sieve[2] = is_prime(2)) ...` is the same as simply `if (is_prime(2)) ...`, but of course it also modifies `sieve[2]`.

Comment: this line your provided returns

    sieve [2] 1 (bool1, is_prime(2) 2

and after changing is_prime(2) to is_prime(7) it prints "7". For "8" it prints 0

Comment: @astose: your output shows `is_prime` is returning its input in many cases, probably because the same accumulator CPU register is meant to hold the `x` parameter and later the returned value and you're not hitting an explicit `return` statement - see my UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

It assigns the right hand operand to left, and returns the left operand.Since you are assigning true to your variable, it evaluates to true. If you set your variable to `false`, you don't get the output, e.g:

```
bool x;
if(x = false) 
    printf("this won't be printed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the equal affect the left operator with the value of the right operator then test the value. So the result must be the value of the right operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in `is_prime` will never run for the check `x == i` will be true, because it runs as long as `x != i`. Those two conditions are mutually exclusive.

That means the function will end without a `return` statement, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Apparently that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if ( sieve[2] = is_prime(2) )
```

contains an assignment, not a comparison.
As the value of an assignment is the value assigned, it is true whenever `is_prime(2)` is.

*However*, let's look at your `is_prime` and see what happens if we pass it a `2`...

```
bool is_prime(int x) {
    unsigned int i,j,k;
```

So far, so good, but `j` and `k` are never used, so they shouldn't really be here.

```
    if (x < 2) return false;
```

2 isn't less than 2, so we'll continue...

```
    else {
        for (i=2; i!=x; i++) {
```

OK, set `i = 2`, and compare it to `x` which is `2`, and... oops, `i` is *equal* to `x`, so we'll abandon the loop immediately...

```
            if (x == i) return true;
            else if (x % i == 0) return false;
        }
    }
```

... and fall through here, where we're not returning a value like we promised, and causing undefined behaviour.

```
}
```

So, your program is undefined (you really should switch on compiler warnings, or start listening to them).
And this happens on *every* number that is prime.

You can rewrite the loop like this:

```
    for (i=2; i <= x; i++) {
        if (x == i) return true;
        else if (x % i == 0) return false;
    }
```

or

```
    for (i=2; i < x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
```

**Why does `if (is_prime(2))` appear to work?**

(Since this code is undefined, the following is largely speculation and should only be taken with suitable measures of salt.)

Often, when a function is supposed to return something *but doesn't*, the calling function will just grab whatever is stored in the place where the return value *should have been* and use that.
This value is in this case very likely not the same as the bit pattern that represents `true`, so will *compare* unequal to `true`, in `if (is_prime(2) == true)`.
It will however, also very likely, not be the bit pattern that represents `false` either, so will be considered `true` in a conditional, `if(is_prime(2))`.